# Cassandra: List all tables in keyspace based on restriction such as LIKE or CONTAINS?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have many tables per keyspace, therefore I would like to filter the tables based on restriction criteria. I tried this query but it is not really giving the intended result that I want:

```
SELECT table_name FROM system_schema.tables 
WHERE keyspace_name = 'test' 
and table_name >= 'test_001_%';
```

The output shown is:

```
'table_name'
---------------------
 'test_001_metadata'    
 'test_001_time1'    
 'test_001_time2'    
 'test_001_time3'    
 'test_001_time4'    
 'test_002_metadata'    
 'test_002_time1'    
 'test_002_time2'
 'test_002_time3'
```

What I really want is: 
The output shown is:

```
'table_name'
---------------------
 'test_001_metadata'    
 'test_001_time1'    
 'test_001_time2'    
 'test_001_time3'    
 'test_001_time4'
```

The other way out is to use `LIKE` keyword by creating secondary index on table_name. But I am a bit skeptical if it might cause problem as it is a system table. Another concern is, does clustering column ACTUALLY support secondary index?

Comment: Although I'm not sure about this, if the previous query works then this should also work, 
`SELECT table_name FROM system_schema.tables 
WHERE keyspace_name = 'test' 
and table_name >= 'test_001_%' and table_name <='test_002_%';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `SASI` index with mode contains on the `table_name` column after removing the previous index and try the query as

```
SELECT table_name FROM system_schema.tables 
WHERE keyspace_name = 'test' 
and table_name LIKE '%test_001_%';
```

The command to create a `SASI` index with mode contains is as follows:

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX ON system_schema.tables(table_name) 
USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' 
WITH OPTIONS = {'analyzer_class': 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.StandardAnalyzer', 
'case_sensitive': 'false', 'tokenization_normalize_uppercase': 'true', 'mode': 'CONTAINS'}
```

And for your second question, you cannot create secondary index on anything which is part of `PRIMARY KEY`.